# Node JS MySQL Authentication

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to node JS. I am working on authenticating users against backend MYSQL.

Here is the code snippet of authentication

```
function Authenticate(username, password, fn) {
     connection.connect();
     var user;
     connection.query('SELECT * from Users where username = ' +
         connection.escape(username) + ' and password =' + connection.escape(password),
         function(err, rows) {
             user = rows[0].username;
         });
     if (!user) {
         return fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
     } else {
         return fn(null, user);
     }
     connection.end();
 }
```

This is my call back function.

```
app.post('/Login', function(req, res) {
    Authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (user) {
            req.session.regenerate(function() {
                req.session.user = user;
                req.session.success = 'Authenticated as ' + user;
                res.redirect('Home');
            });
        } else {
            req.session.error = 'Authentication failed, please check your username and password.';
            res.redirect('Login');
        }
    });
})
```

I am getting an error, which i cannot get my head around.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined
    at /...../.../node_modules/app.js:42:23
    at Authenticate (/..../..../node_modules/app.js:82:11).
```

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: It seems to be saying that req.session doesn't exist at this line:             req.session.error = 'Authentication failed, please check your username and password.';

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite get it. But i ve tried commenting both success and error session message but still getting same error.

Comment: Perhaps req.session doesn't exist at all. The only thing your error is telling me is that req.session is undefined. As far as your code goes, it looks good.

Comment: Yes correct. Thanks i ve removed entire session details and it is working now. Still Authentication is not working. But i guess it has got to do with my DB.

Comment: NP, I'll just put this as the answer, and you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Takes the else out and see if any other req.session functions properly if not check if middleware is configured correctly for express validator